# How to access the internal bucket/array of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

From what I understand, if my dictionary looks something like
`{'apple': 0 , 'ball': 100 , 'cat': 121 }`, then there is an internal array in dictionary, which might look something like

```
_internal_bucket = [null, null, '0', null, '100', '121', null, null, null]
```

the hash method for apple, ball, and cat gives 2,4,5 respectively, which are used as indexes in the internal array.

My question is, how, to access that internal_bucket? or that atleast the hash indexes (like [2,4,5])

Comment: you cannot do that in python, you can do it using a C module, but you'll have to read its data directly, not use the python C API.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it just out of curiosity or do you actually have a purpose for it? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). If you do have a purpose for it, which implementation and version are you using?

Comment: @wjandrea purely out of curiosity